# unable to add x-axis label name for the graph (svg graph)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I have this codepen https://codepen.io/a166617/pen/NWvZGLd and i am trying to put an x-axis label for the graph. As you can see, the y-axis label has 0,25,50,75,100 shown. These are static values. But the x-axis label names are dynamic and i am not able to put the label names.

I tried putting this line of code `<div style={xtitle}>{entry.name}</div>` into below code as follows but i cannot see the x-axis label. can someone please suggest where i am going wrong.

```
const rows = (entry, rowIndex) => {
    return entry.bars.map((bar, index) => {
      console.log('bar', entry, bar)
      const graphHeight = 490 - 5;
      const height = (bar.value / entry.total) * graphHeight;
      const y = (bar.y / entry.total) * graphHeight;
      return (
        <>
        <g key={Math.random()}>
          <rect
            width={50}
            height={height}
            fill={bar.color}
            x={100 + rowIndex * 60} // multiply with the width (50) + 10 for space
            y={490 - y - height}
          />
          <text
            x={125 + rowIndex * 60}                // visible centre point of your bar
            y={490 - y - height/2}
            dy="0.5em"            // adjusts the text y position to adjust for text descenders.
            textAnchor="middle"   // centre the text horizontall at x
            class="bar-label" 
            style={{ fill: 'white',
  fontSize: '12px' }}// styling for this text 
            >{`${bar.color === '#ffcc00' && bar.value === 100 ? 'X': bar.value}`}</text>
          </g>
          <div style={xtitle}>{entry.name}</div> 
        </>
      );
    });
  };
```

I am trying to achieve the end result as this screenshot. The screenshot has x-axis label names as 'Tom, Emma, Lucy, Kim, Steve'. Similarly, i am trying to show x-axis label on my codepen.

[image]

Comment: HI check this, https://codepen.io/Free_Soul/pen/WNZNdJo

Comment: @AmanSharma- hi, can you pls confirm the above codepen of yours. I see the same code as mine.

Comment: i just edit the your code, didn't you see any label below the bars?

Comment: I see, the height of the graph was 500px and was hiding the text. now i can see your code and the changes reflect on graph. can you post only your code as an answer so i can accept it

Comment: okay............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const ReleaseScopeCharts = () => {
  const data = [
    {
      name: 'Transit',
      passed: 100,
      skipped: 0,
      failed: 0,
      untested: 0
    },
    {
      name: 'Transit',
      passed: 25,
      skipped: 50,
      failed: 25,
      untested: 0
    },
    {
      name: 'Access',
      passed: 0,
      skipped: 0,
      failed: 0,
      untested: 100
    }
  ];

  // Basic style
  const newCardStyle = {
    display: 'flex'
  };
  
  const xtitle = {
    color: 'red',
    marginTop: '20%',
    transform: 'rotate(-45deg)'
  };
  const contentStyle = {
    display: 'flex',
    flexFlow: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  };
  
  const width = 90;

  const colors = ['#30D158', '#005EA7', '#FF453A', '#ffcc00'];
  const entries = data.map(d => ({
    name: d.name,
    total: ['passed', 'skipped', 'failed', 'untested'].reduce(
      (acc, key) => acc + d[key],
      0
    ),
    bars: ['passed', 'skipped', 'failed', 'untested']
      .map((key, i) => ({
        value: d[key],
        color: colors[i],
        y:
          key === 'passed'
            ? 0
            : key === 'skipped'
            ? d['passed']
            : d['skipped'] + d['passed'],
      }))
      .filter(bar => bar.value),
  }));

  const rows = (entry, rowIndex) => {
    return entry.bars.map((bar, index) => {
      console.log('bar', entry, bar)
      const graphHeight = 490 - 5;
      const height = (bar.value / entry.total) * graphHeight;
      const y = (bar.y / entry.total) * graphHeight;
      return (
        <>
        <g key={Math.random()}>
          <rect
            width={50}
            height={height}
            fill={bar.color}
            x={100 + rowIndex * 60} // multiply with the width (50) + 10 for space
            y={490 - y - height}
          />
          <text
            x={125 + rowIndex * 60}                // visible centre point of your bar
            y={490 - y - height/2}
            dy="0.5em"            // adjusts the text y position to adjust for text descenders.
            textAnchor="middle"   // centre the text horizontall at x
            class="bar-label" 
            style={{ fill: 'white',
  fontSize: '12px' }}// styling for this text 
            >{`${bar.color === '#ffcc00' && bar.value === 100 ? 'X': bar.value}`}</text>
          
          <text
            x={125 + rowIndex * 60}
            y={520}
            textAnchor="middle"
            class="bottom-label"
            style={{ fill: '#000',
  fontSize: '12px' }}
            >label</text>
          </g>
        </>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
    <div className="new-card" style={newCardStyle}>
      <svg class="graph">
        <g class="grid x-grid" id="xGrid">
            <line x1="90" x2="90" y1="5" y2="490"></line>
          </g>
          <g class="grid y-grid" id="yGrid">
            <line x1="90" x2="805" y1="490" y2="490"></line>
          </g>
          <g class="labels y-labels">
            <text x="80" y="15">100</text>
            <text x="80" y="131">75</text>
            <text x="80" y="248">50</text>
            <text x="80" y="373">25</text>
            <text x="80" y="500">0</text>
            <text x="60" y="200" class="label-title">Pass %</text>  
        </g>
        <g>
          {entries.map((entry, indx) => (
            rows(entry, indx)
          ))}
        </g>
      </svg>
      
    </div>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render the component to the browser
ReactDOM.render(
  // Pass in props
    <ReleaseScopeCharts />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.mGraph > svg {
  position: relative;
  left: -40rem;
  top: -.65rem;
}

.mGraph > div {
  position: relative;
  left: -39rem;
  top: -.65rem;
}

.mGraph > text {
  position: relative;
  left: -50rem;
}

.graph .labels.x-labels {
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.graph .labels.y-labels {
  text-anchor: end;
}


.graph {
  height: 500px;
  width: 1200px;
}

.graph .grid {
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-dasharray: 0;
  stroke-width: 1;
}

.labels {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.label-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  fill: black;
  margin-left: 50%
}

.data {
  fill: red;
  stroke-width: 1; 
}
svg{overflow: visible}
.bottom-label{font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```